# Get ID of autoincrement field in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, auto-increment

I'm using SQLite database.
I want make an insert and get the field ID (autogenerated) of this insert.
The field ID is an autoincrement key.
I'm using the statement

```
  SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

and this works fine.

The problem is when I have many concurrent insert into the table: in this case it possible it returns me an ID associated to another insert (not my insert).

What can I do, for making the operation in autonoumus manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html);

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of **the last row
>   insert from the database connection which invoked the function**.

So, as long as you're calling the select on the same connection right after you did the insert, other simultaneous users are entirely independent and won't cause the returned value to be wrong.

Comment: But I'm using Android, and I don't know if the two query are referred to the same connection to db

Comment: Ok, I think db.close() for close connection is the way for closing database connectio. Thank you for suggestion :)